# fazer a multiplicação de valores usando operador de soma e while

Tags: javascript, operadores, while

```
 var  n1 = Number(window.prompt(" digite o primeiro número "));   
 var  n2 = Number(window.prompt(" digite o segundo número ")); 

 var soma;

 var num = 0; 

        while( num < n1)

    {


        var num = n1+n2+n1;




       num++;
    }

 alert(soma);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se pegarmos `5 x 7`, que dá `35`, podemos ver desta forma:

```
 7 + 7 + 7 + 7 + 7   n2
└────────┬────────┘ 
         5           n1
```

Transportando isso para um algoritmo, significa que temos que adicionar o valor `n2` (7, no exemplo) por `n1` vezes (5, no exemplo).

Que pode ser implementado assim:

```
var  n1 = Number(window.prompt(" digite o primeiro número "));   
var  n2 = Number(window.prompt(" digite o segundo número ")); 

var soma = 0;
var num = 0; 

while( num < n1 )       // vamos efetuar a soma n1 vezes
{
  var soma = soma + n2; // e, em cada vez, adicionamos n2 ao total
  num++;
}

alert(soma);
```

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/oYYyJO)**.

Comment: eu queria que fazer uma multiplicação usando o operador de soma, multiplicar os dois valores de entrada

Comment: É exatamente o que o código acima faz. Se você coloca 7 e 5, ele mostra 35. Se coloca 11 e 11 ele mostra 121, e assim por diante.